# When should I close the db connection?

Tags: php, sqlconnection

Is it a must to close the connection in PHP script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the configuration of your DB server, there is a limit on the possible number of connections opened to it at the same time.

So, if your script :

- does some queries
- and, then, does some long calculations without doing any query anymore

It can be interesting to close the connection after having done all your queries -- and to only open the connection when it's becoming needed.

Still, note that connections are closed when the script ends, anyway ; which means that if you don't have a wya to be sure that you have finished doing queries, you don't **need** to close the connection : keeping it opened allows you to do some additionnal queries whenever it's necessary.

*(This is particularly true is your pages are built using several distinct and independant components, that are all susceptible to do DB queries)*

For the applications I write, I generally :

- Open the connection on the first query *(Which means no connection is opened if no query is sent)*
- Never close the connection : as my pages asre built using lots of components,  I have no way of knowing for sure that the connection won't be needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. As a general rule is this: open connections as late as possible, and close them as soon as possible. In most modern systems/environments connections are pooled, so there's no problem (performance hit) in constantly opening and closing them.

Answer (score 0):

When the php scrip finishes running, all objects, variables are lost even the db connection.else with the new db connection object. But as *rule of thumb*, it is better to open connection and close it when you don't need it.